# How to set frame of elements inside CollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a custom cell class that looks like this:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    var textLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var buttonView: UIButton!
    var id: String = String()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)



        let textFrame = CGRect(x: buttonView.center.x - self.frame.width/2, y: 90, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height/3)
        textLabel = UILabel(frame: textFrame)
        textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.smallSystemFontSize())
        textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        contentView.addSubview(textLabel)



buttonView = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
            buttonView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width / 2 - frame.width * 0.4, y: 0 + textLabel.frame.size.height, width: frame.size.width * 0.8, height:  frame.size.height * 0.8 )

            contentView.addSubview(buttonView)           

        }
    }
```

and the func where I dequeue cells looks like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        switch collectionView{
        case collectionViewOne!:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewDetailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewDetailCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cellHeightOne = cell.frame.height
            cell.productLabel.text = "\(array[indexPath.row].name)"
            cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0

            let myText = NSString(format: self.array[indexPath.row].description)

            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
            paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified
            let attributes: NSDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12), NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: 0, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()]
            let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: myText as String, attributes: attributes as [NSObject : AnyObject])

            cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedText
            cell.textLabel.sizeToFit()
            cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.textLabel)


            return cell
```

I want for my labels text height to move the button down, but nothing happens, i also tried to find out the height and to send it to cell something like:
cell.textHeigth = textHeigth, and use textHeigth in 
`buttonView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width / 2 - frame.width * 0.4, y: 0 + textHeigth, width: frame.size.width , height: frame.size.height * 0.8)` 
but then i get the error that some variable is nil, but I tryed printing the variable and before sending it to customClass it is not nil

Answer (score 1):

Implement the below delegate method to set width and height of collection view cell

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return CGSizeMake(width,height);
 }
```

Comment: that is not exactly what i am looking for but i figured it out, thnx

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put my button under the text with this code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewDetailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewDetailCell
let myText = NSString(format: newString)

                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
                paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified
                let attributes: NSDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12), NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: 0, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()]
                let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: myText as String, attributes: attributes as [NSObject : AnyObject])

                cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedText
                cell.textLabel.sizeToFit()
                cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.textLabel)

                cell.buttonView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200 + cell.textLabel.frame.size.height, width: 10, height: 10)

return cell
    }
```

You have to do everything in this cellForItemAtIndexPath